# rate limiting in Dropwizard per user

Tags: dropwizard, rate-limiting

How can I setup rate limiting in Dropwizard per user?
I am doing user authentication and authorization and on the top of that I want rate limiting also so that user can not bombard my application with huge number of calls. the rate limits might vary per user according to use cases.

Comment: There is http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/dos-filter.html Mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13900097/25429 This also looks interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36082010/25429

Comment: Doing this into the java is too late. Should be done by nginx or haproxy with a rate per IP